# Как вывести теги таксономии в алфавитном порядке?

Tags: php, wordpress

С помощью get_terms получаю теги таксономии 
Но они перемешаны, как можно их отсортировать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В параметрах функции можно указать параметры `orderby` и `order`.

`orderby` - Поле по которому сортировать результат.
`order` - Направление сортировки, указанной в параметре `orderby`.

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'hide_empty'  => 0,  
    'orderby'     => 'name',
    'order'       => 'ASC',
    'taxonomy'    => 'category',
) );
```

Подробнее про параметры функции `get_terms()`: https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_terms